# Recursion in python - why isn't the sum overriden by 0 everytime the fuction is called within itself?

Tags: python, recursion, sum

I have a perfectly working recursion:

```
def sum_of_list(a_list):
    sum = 0
    for element in a_list:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            sum += sum_of_list(element)
        else:
            sum += element
    return sum


some_list = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]]
print(sum_of_list(some_list))
```

But I don't understand why the `sum` isn't overriden by 0 every time the line `sum += sum_of_list(element)` is executed? Because it calls the function back from the start where the sum equals to 0.

Comment: Every call to `sum_of_list` has it own local variables (like `sum`). Every recursive call does not share the same data. This is the same as any other function call.

Answer (score 1):

Each time sum_of_list() is called, the "sum = 0" line creates a local variable with the value 0 unique to that call of the function. If you had a global variable declared outside of this function declaration that is used as your "sum" variable, then it would be reset to 0 I believe

```
sum = 0
def sum_of_list(a_list):
    sum = 0
    for element in a_list:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            sum += sum_of_list(element)
        else:
            sum += element
    return sum
some_list = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]]
print(sum_of_list(some_list))
```